# Pagebeforeshow not fired on second time change Page event

Tags: jquery-mobile

In Jquery mobile-1.1.1 pagebeforechange, pagebeforeshow events not fired second time call of $mobile.changepage.

**From Home page:**

```js
function scan() {
        window.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(function(result) {
                alert("Barcode-->"+result.text);
            barcode=result.text;
            $.mobile.changePage("scan.html",{reloadPage:true,transition: "none"});
        }, function(error) {
            alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
        });
}
```

**Page Load:**

```js
$("#scan_page").live("pagebeforeshow",function(event){
        alert("Scan page Init");
            loadScannedItems();
});

function loadScannedItems()
{
    //append scanned items to list
    // called Scan() again
}
```

**pagebeforeshow** event fired first time the page loads,again I go to scan function call the changePage, but pagebeforeshow not fired. What is the problem in this code?

Also created  button with data-role="button" dynamically. But still it displayed as link?

Comment: If the button was created dynamically, you will need to do a `.button()` on it to integrate it into jquery mobile.

Comment: Add Class Name to buttons as class=fnbuttons.Then after created button dynamically do as below.                       $('.fnbuttons').button();          // initialize button
$('.fnbuttons').button('refresh'); // then call refresh                                         i want answer for my first question pagebefore show not fired?