# pagebeforeshow event not fired after call to changepage

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery

I'm just starting out in jQM development and have hit a bit of a brick wall.

In short, I have a javascript file and two pages. In the main page (index.html) I'm populating a listview dynamically, and registering the tap event for each and every item for this listview. The on tap event, in return, calls the changepage method to an external page (details.html). This works fine 100% of the time.

In the javascript file, I'm registering for events on pagebeforeshow for the details.html page. This works okay first time out, but any subsequent calls are not triggering the pagebeforeshow event at all. Having had a closer look i can see that the pagechange is being called, pagebeforechange event is being fired okay, but the pagebeforeshow is only fired for that particular item only (untill a complete refresh).

I have set up a sample for you to be able to look at. I would seriously appreciate any feedback given. For all I know - I may be using the wrong events!?

The closest post I could find on SO was [Pagebeforeshow not fired on second time change Page event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12005305/pagebeforeshow-not-fired-on-second-time-change-page-event) however it doesn't particularly deal with listviews so I'm not sure if it's related or not.

Thanks,

Matt

Index.html

```
   <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- All Stock Search -->
    <div id="idxPage" data-role="page" style="height:50px;" data-title="Main Menu">
        <div data-role="header" class="sixteen columns">
            <a href="index.html" data-icon="home" data-direction="reverse">Home</a>
            <h1>
                <a href="index.html" data-icon="home" data-direction="reverse"> Test </a>
            </h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content" style="text-align:center;">    
        <ul id="ListItems" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true">
        </ul>
        </div><!-- /content -->
        <footer>
            <div data-role="footer" data-id="connfooter" class="ui-footer ui-bar-a" role="contentinfo"> 
                <h4 style="text-align: left;" class="ui-title" tabindex="0" role="heading" aria-level="1">

                </h4>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
```

details.html

```
   <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- All Stock Search -->
    <div id="detailsPage" data-role="page" style="height:50px;" data-title="Main Menu">
        <div data-role="header" class="sixteen columns">
            <a href="index.html" data-icon="home" data-direction="reverse">Home</a>
            <h1>
                <a href="index.html" data-icon="home" data-direction="reverse"> Test </a>
            </h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content" style="text-align:center;">    
        <b>Page placeholder</b>
        </div><!-- /content -->
        <footer>
            <div data-role="footer" data-id="connfooter" class="ui-footer ui-bar-a" role="contentinfo"> 
                <h4 style="text-align: left;" class="ui-title" tabindex="0" role="heading" aria-level="1">

                </h4>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
```

jquery.custom.js (JS Library)

```
$(document).on("pagebeforechange", function (event, data) {
    alert('changing page...');
});
$(document).on('pageinit', function () {
$("#detailsPage").off();
$("#detailsPage").on("pagebeforeshow", function(event){
    alert('about to show page...');
});

$("#ListItems").off();
$("#ListItems").on("listviewbeforefilter", function (e, data) {
    var $ul = $(this),
                $input = $(data.input),
                value = $input.val(),
                html = "";
    $ul.html("");

    if (value && value.length > 2) {
        $ul.html("<li><div class='ui-loader'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-loading'></span></div></li>");
        $ul.listview("refresh");

        var max = 200;
        var limit = 0;

        var itemslist = [
            {"id":1, "desc":"item1"},
            {"id":2, "desc":"item2"},
            {"id":3, "desc":"testitm1"},
            {"id":4, "desc":"testitm2"}
            ];

        $.each(itemslist, function (i, val) {

            if (limit < max) {
                if (val.desc.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) != -1) {
                    $ul.append('<li id="' + val.id + '" ><a style="text-align:left" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" >' + val.desc + '</a></li>');

                    $('#' + val.id).off();
                    $('#' + val.id).on('tap', function (event) {
                        var elementId = $(this).attr('id');

                        $.mobile.changePage("details.html?Id="+elementId, { data: { "Id": elementId} });
                    });

                    limit++;
                }
            }

        });

        $ul.listview("refresh");
        $ul.trigger("updatelayout");

    }
});

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are incorrectly binding page event.

Instead of  this:

```
$("#detailsPage").off();
$("#detailsPage").on("pagebeforeshow", function(event){
    alert('about to show page...');
});
```

Use this:

```
$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#detailsPage",function(event){
    alert('about to show page...');
});
```

Remember, jQuery Mobile page events must always be added with event delegation.

Also your don't need to use off() with page events, they do not suffer from multiple event binding problem. If you have more question feel free to ask in comments.

Comment: Excellent. Worked straight away. Thank you for the detail provided!